# Mockito 3 mock method of an autowired class

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-test 2.2.0` which includes `Mockito 3.1.0`.

I would like to test this class:

```java
@RestController
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired MyAutowired myAutowired;

    public int myClassMethod(int i) {
        return myAutowired.methodToMock(i);
    }
}
```

Which use this one:

```java
@Service
public class MyAutowired {

    public int methodToMock(int i) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

In my test I would like to run `myClassMethod` but with a mocked behavior for `methodToMock`. Ideally I would like to check if `methodToMock` was called with the expected argument.

Here is what I tried so far:

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(Config.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyClassTest {
    @Autowired MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private MyAutowired myAutowired;

    @BeforeEach
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(myAutowired.methodToMock(any()).thenReturn(1);

        int shouldBe1ButIs2 = myClass.myClassMethod(2);
    }

}
```

What's wrong with that ? And how to make `myClass.myClassMethod(2)` return 1 ?

Comment: Don't use field injection. If you used constructor injection, you wouldn't have to bother with all these annotations to try and and get the autowiring to work in the test. You don't *care* how the class gets its dependency for the sake of the test. You just want to make an instance of `MyClass`. If you used constructor injection you could just do `new MyClass(myMockAutowired)` directly in the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your object `MyClass` is not referring to the right mock instance. The `MyAutowired` has to injected into `MyClass`.

You have two options:

1. Creating a `setMyAutowired` method in `MyClass` and pass the `MyAutowired` instance to it in your test class.
2. Replacing `@Autowired` with `@InjectMocks` annotation on `MyClass`. In this way, an instance of `MyClass` will be created and mocks objects which you declared in your test will be injected automatically in it.

I normally use the second option, which is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, it works well! Little correction: it's `@InjectMocks`

Comment: @Izaya you're right, let me correct my typos. Thanks.